# Is it possible to listen to a notification and do something as a callback

Tags: postgresql

I have been reading this [topic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) in Postgres documentation which is about Notify and Listen. They have provided an example which is:

```
LISTEN virtual;
NOTIFY virtual;
-- Asynchronous notification "virtual" received from server process with PID 8448.
NOTIFY virtual, 'This is the payload';
-- Asynchronous notification "virtual" with payload "This is the payload" received from server process with PID 8448.
```

My problem with this example is that, when it comes to Pub/Sub, I need to listen to a subject and react to it. In this example `LISTEN virtual;` is just declared and then left as it is, so how can I really listen to that subject so that when something is publish then I can raise and event let's say by just printing the message?

For example, consider this pseudocode:

```
chan := LISTEN virtual;
for message in chan {
    print message;
}
```

UPDATE: I would like to publish a message to Postgres from a client application, then I want to write a procedure/function/whatever in Postgres to listen for that message and then do something when it receives it. For example, I want to publish a JSON object using a client application and I want to extract some data and add them to multiple tables.

Comment: You need to write a client.  Which must be done in some language.  Which you should specify.

Comment: @jjanes: No, that is not what I am asking. I am asking in particular about a pl/pgsql or sql way to do this.

Comment: @jjanes: If you mean that it cannot be done in pl/pgsql or sql then why is there a `LISTEN` keyword. That would make it pretty useless, right?

Comment: Why use an event notification here? If you want to handle things on the server, I would have thought, that simply using a stored procedure would be easier? Instead of triggering a notification, you simply call the procedure. Besides `LISTEN` is to be used on the client side, not in the server. The concrete (client-side) mechanism depends on the client library in use (libpq, JDBC, whatever). See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-listen.html

Comment: @Dirk: I just provided an example. I actually need to learn what can be done purely in Postgres and what cannot be done. I'm designing something on top of this database that's why I need to know if it can be done or not.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in PL/pgSQL. It certainly works in client code, but perhaps you can make it work in a C function or in a custom background worker.

Comment: " why is there a LISTEN keyword"  How would you tell it to listen?  The processing of the messages can't be done in SQL. but it would be a cruel and pointless jape to make the LISTEN command itself need to come over a separate channel too.